# Which blockchain is best to implement tamper proof document?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, iota

I am just starting out as a blockchain developer and I want a blockchain service except Ethereum (already implemented) to store a hash (SHA256 and ISCC hashes) of a document in a blockchain so that it can verify its validity and is tamper proof. There is already a UI to generate hashes and I need a blockchain to store the hashes

My need is:

I want to have a blockchain service with low transaction cost and high transaction speed. Also, I want that the hashes be stored in the blockchain for a long period of time (5 years). Which blockchain would be best fit for this usecase?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you need to understand who will be the users of your project. Accordingly, it is necessary to use the public or private blockchain further. For public blockchains, the choice is quite small - of those that will live for 5 years, these are most likely Bitcoin and Ethereum. For private blockchains, the choice is much wider: Ethereum / Quorum, Hyper Ledger Fabic, Corda and many others. Each of them has its own complexity of deployment, development and support.

But the very first question - why do you need blockchain? To store hashes of files, you can use IPFS or cloud storages, certifying them with a digital signature of a certain "notary" participant or, for example, the owner of the file. In terms of performance and low cost, these are the most efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have a blockchain service with low transaction cost and high transaction speed.

Everyone wants this, so you are not along with your requirements.

> Also, I want that the hashes be stored in the blockchain for a long period of time (5 years). Which blockchain would be best fit for this usecase?

Currently all blockchains assume the state is stored permanently - or to the end of the world or until nobody runs nodes anymore. Whichever comes first. There is a risk of dead chain, so whatever you pick might not be around after five years. However this is a business discussion, so it is hard to answer to this one on StackOverflow.

For your use case, it does sound you do not need a blockchain at all, but just having a public data storage that is prepaid for up to five years.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer. I want blockchain for time stamping so that it can be made tamper proof.

Comment: Tamper-proof logs have been part of Linux since early 2010. The feature is called forward secure sealing. You do not need blockchain for it https://lwn.net/Articles/512895/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Emercoin NVS](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emernvs) for upload your hashes. Service [emernotar.io](https://emernotar.io/) already does so. Also, you can use [File Validator](https://emercoin.com/en/news/file-validator) service, all scripts are open source and available on [Github](https://github.com/emercoin/FV).